# Database not updating (integration in woocommerce)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am using Wordpress / WooCommerce. My client doesn't want users to have to create an account to buy something, but still wants to store the customer address so it auto populates when the user comes back to the site for a future purpose.

I had a school project where I saved a note to a database (plain text in a textbox). It grabs the "notes" already in the database, and shows them to you, with an option to update the note. This updates the database entry.

I am trying to adapt this code to work with woocommerce. I haven't changed much besides the name of the table.

The database connects fine, and it pulls the content from the table as requested.
*My issue is*: the database is not updating the entry when I click "update". I'm not sure if this is because I'm trying to use it within woocommerce, and the shopping cart is causing issues? But it's practically the same code as my working school project.

---

**You can see it working here (once you add something to your cart):** http://www.onelifehealthycuisine.com/mobile/checkout/

Currently, I'm just trying to get it to update the address, once that works I'll add in the other cell's to update.

---

**Database**

Name: tbl_stored_address

| ID | ip_address | address | city | province | postal |

**Test Entry:** 2, 96.48.1.29, 123 fake street, vancouver, bc, v3c 5r6

---

```
function dbConnect(){
    $db_host = 'xxx.xxx.com';
    $db_un = 'xxxx';
    $db_pass = 'xxxx';
    $db_name = 'xxxx';
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8",$db_un,$db_pass);

    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_un, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());    
}
dbConnect();

function getAddys(){
    $user_id = '96.48.1.29'; //get user IP
    $query = "SELECT tbl_stored_address.address, tbl_stored_address.id FROM tbl_stored_address WHERE tbl_stored_address.ip_address ='".$user_id."';";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    //saves number of rows returned
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='form-checkout.php' method='post'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<textarea name='address".$row['id']."' id='address".$row['id']."'>".$row['address']."</textarea><br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/><input type='submit' value='Update Note(s)' name='updateNote'/><br/>";
    echo "</form>";
}
//this will check if the user clicked on "update" for a note, and then update the correct notes using the ID
if(isset($_POST['updateNote']))
{
    $user_id = '96.48.1.29'; //get user IP
    $query = "SELECT tbl_stored_address.id FROM tbl_stored_address WHERE tbl_stored_address.ip_address ='".$user_id."';";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        if((isset($_POST['address'.$row['id'].'']))){
            $value = $_POST['address'.$row['id'].''];
            $theID = $row['id'];
            $query2 = "UPDATE tbl_stored_address SET tbl_stored_address.address='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' WHERE tbl_stored_address.id ='".$theID."';";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

?>      

<h2>Delivery Address</h2><br/><br/>

<?php getAddys(); ?>
```

---

******UPDATE******

I've tried adding the code to a page without woocommerce and accessing the the PHP page directly, and it updates the database fine: http://www.onelifehealthycuisine.com/mobile/wp-content/themes/onelife/page-test.php

So is it the fact that the URL doesn't end with a .php file? Or something in the woocommerce template not allowing me to run the form properly? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Any particular reason you create a PDO object, and then proceed to use nothing but deprecated `mysql_` functions?

Comment: Because that's what they taught us in school. I know it's the not the best code, but right now I just need it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tbl_stored_address.id` is an `int`, this :

```
WHERE tbl_stored_address.id ='".$theID."'
```

won't match anything. Use

```
WHERE tbl_stored_address.id =".$theID."
```

That being said, you shouldn't using the `mysql_` functions, and DEFINITELY should not be building your query using string concatenation. That being said, this is your script updated to use the MySQLi extension:

```
<?php
    function dbConnect() 
    {
        $db_host = 'xxx.xxx.com';
        $db_un = 'xxxx';
        $db_pass = 'xxxx';
        $db_name = 'xxxx';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_un, $db_pass, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error());       
    }

    dbConnect();

    function getAddys() 
    {
        $user_id = '96.48.1.29'; //get user IP
        $query = "SELECT tbl_stored_address.address, tbl_stored_address.id FROM tbl_stored_address WHERE tbl_stored_address.ip_address = '" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        //saves number of rows returned
        $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($conn, $result);
        echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='form-checkout.php' method='post'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn, $result))
        {
            echo "<textarea name='address".$row['id']."' id='address" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['address'] . "</textarea><br/>";
        }
        echo "<br/><input type='submit' value='Update Note(s)' name='updateNote'/><br/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }

    //this will check if the user clicked on "update" for a note, and then update the correct notes using the ID
    if(isset($_POST['updateNote']))
    {
        $user_id = '96.48.1.29'; //get user IP
        $query = "SELECT tbl_stored_address.id FROM tbl_stored_address WHERE tbl_stored_address.ip_address = '" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn, $result))
        {
            if((isset($_POST['address' . $row['id']])))
            {
                $value = $_POST['address' . $row['id']];
                $theID = $row['id'];
                $query2 = "UPDATE tbl_stored_address SET tbl_stored_address.address = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "' WHERE tbl_stored_address.id = " . $theID . ";";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            }
        }
    }  
?>

<h2>Delivery Address</h2><br /><br />

<?php getAddys(); ?>
```

The MySQLi extensions reverse the order of the parameters from what you may be used to, with the connection being the first parameter. Like the MySQL extension, if you omit the connection object, the extension functions will attempt to reuse an existing open connection.

Since we **really** don't want to use string concatenation in our SQL, you need to get familiar with using prepared statements, which the MySQli extension supports. Here's your code with prepared statements:

```
<?php
    function dbConnect() 
    {
        $db_host = 'xxx.xxx.com';
        $db_un = 'xxxx';
        $db_pass = 'xxxx';
        $db_name = 'xxxx';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_un, $db_pass, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error());  
    }

    dbConnect();

    function getAddys() 
    {
        $user_id = '96.48.1.29'; //get user IP
        if ($query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT tbl_stored_address.address, tbl_stored_address.id FROM tbl_stored_address WHERE tbl_stored_address.ip_address = ?;")) 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $user_id); # 's' indicates that this parameter is a string
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $row);

            echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='form-checkout.php' method='post'>";
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch(($query))
            {
                echo "<textarea name='address" . $row['id'] . "' id='address" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['address'] . "</textarea><br/>";
            }
            echo "<br/><input type='submit' value='Update Note(s)' name='updateNote'/><br/>";
            echo "</form>";

            mysqli_stmt_close($query); 
        }
    }

    //this will check if the user clicked on "update" for a note, and then update the correct notes using the ID
    if(isset($_POST['updateNote']))
    {
        $user_id = '96.48.1.29'; //get user IP
        if ($query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT tbl_stored_address.address, tbl_stored_address.id FROM tbl_stored_address WHERE tbl_stored_address.ip_address = ?;")) 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $user_id); # 's' indicates that this parameter is a string
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $row);

            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch(($query))
            {
                if((isset($_POST['address' . $row['id']])))
                {
                    $value = $_POST['address' . $row['id']];
                    $theID = $row['id'];

                    if ($updateQuery = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE tbl_stored_address SET tbl_stored_address.address = ? WHERE tbl_stored_address.id = ?;")) 
                    {
                        $updateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_stored_address SET tbl_stored_address.address = ? WHERE tbl_stored_address.id = ?;";

                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updateQuery, "s", $value); # 's' indicates that this parameter is a string
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updateQuery, "i", $theID); # 'i' indicates that this parameter is an integer
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($updateQuery);
                    }
                }
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($query); 
        }
    }  
?>

<h2>Delivery Address</h2><br /><br />

<?php getAddys(); ?>
```

There may be errors in the code above, so caveat emptor.

You can find everything you need to learn the MySQLi extension on the PHP.net website: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. You'll also find the docs for PDO, which was the last extension I used when coding in PHP.

Comment: Thanks @Tieson I will try and read a bit more about MySQLi. Is there a particular reason we can't or shouldn't use mysql_ anymore? It still works. If it's so terrible I wonder why the school that taught me all this hasn't updated their program (I only took the class 6 months ago), and it's a well known institution.

Comment: You should not be using the MySQL extension because it's been officially deprecated. That means that at some point it will be dropped from the official distribution. It's an inherently insecure library. The whole point of the improved extension (the 'i' in MySQLi) is that it addresses quite a few on the problem points in the original extension. It also adds an object-oriented approach. As for why your school hasn't changed? If it's like the college I work at: inertia.

Comment: @KerynGill Also, a good comparison of the various APIs starts here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php